# Use same form for create and edit in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5.3, default-value

I am trying to only use one form for my create and edit form. It is a simple form that I only use HTML and Im using Laravel 5.3. and i dont know how to populate the data when i'm in edit mode. i dont know to use create and edit in one form or view only. cause my other view for edit has a values but now i want to make it one form for my create and edit form. i hope you can help me out. By the way im using ajax for create and update.

**add.blade.php**

```
@extends('main_layout')

@section('content')

<!-- MAIN PANEL -->
<div id="main" role="main">

  <!-- RIBBON -->
  <div id="ribbon">
    <div class="row">

    <!-- breadcrumb -->
    <section class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
         {{$breadcrumb}}            
        </li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <!-- end breadcrumb -->
    <section class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 header-button">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" form="form1" id="btnAdd">{{$saveButtonText}}</button>

    </section>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- END RIBBON -->

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

  <div id="content">
    <section id="" class="">
    <!-- START ROW -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- NEW COL START -->
        <article class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

          <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
          <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-red" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-sortable="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-custombutton="false">


            <header>                  
              <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
              <h2>Personal Information</h2>

            </header>

            <!-- widget div-->
            <div>     

              <!-- widget content -->
              <div class="widget-body no-padding">

              <form class="smart-form" method="post" action="/register" name="myForm" id="form1">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">     

              <div class="alert alert-success fade in" id="alertSuccess">
                <i class="fa-fw fa fa-check"></i>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-danger fade in" id="alertDanger">
                <i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>
                <strong>Failed!</strong> Please Indicate the following info.
              </div>      

              <fieldset>                        
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Full Name</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">

                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">&nbsp;</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name">

                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">&nbsp;</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"placeholder="Last Name">

                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>
                    <section>
                      <label class="label">Present Address</label>
                      <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="present_address" name="present_address" placeholder="Present Address">
                      </label>
                    </section>                        
                    <section>
                      <label class="label">Permanent Address &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="permanent-address">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo" onClick="FillBilling(this.form)"> Same with Present Address</span></label>
                      <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="permanent_address" name="permanent_address" id="lay" placeholder="Permanent Address">
                      </label>
                    </section> 
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Gender</label>
                        <label class="select">
                          <select name="gender" id="Gender" placeholder="Gender">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>                                
                            @foreach (Config::get('constants.GENDER') as $gender)
                            <option value="{{$gender}}">{{$gender}}</option>                                
                            @endforeach
                          </select>
                          <i></i>
                          <!-- <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"> -->
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Birthday</label>
                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                          <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday" class="datepicker" data-dateformat='mm/dd/yy'>
                        </label>
                      </section> 
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Email</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        </label>
                      </section>                         
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="label">Work Phone #</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="tel" name="work_phone" placeholder="Work Phone #" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" class="valid"/>

                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="label">Home Phone #</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="tel" name="home_phone" placeholder="Home Phone #" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" class="valid"/>
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="label">Mobile Phone #</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="tel" name="mobile_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone #" data-mask="(+63) 999-999-9999" class="valid"/>
                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Religion</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="religion" placeholder="Religion">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Citizenship</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Civil Status</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="civil_status" placeholder="Civil Status">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>      
                    <section class="">
                        <label class="label"><br/>Emergency Contacts</label>                            
                    </section>                 
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Name</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_name1" placeholder="Emergency Contact Name 1" id="emergency_name1">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Relationship</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_rel1" placeholder="Emergency Relationship 1">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">
                        <label class="label">Contact #</label>
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_contact1" placeholder="Emergency Contact # 1"onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_name2" placeholder="Emergency Contact Name 2">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_rel2" placeholder="Emergency Relationship 2">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_contact2" placeholder="Emergency Contact # 2"onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_name3" placeholder="Emergency Contact Name 3">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_rel3" placeholder="Emergency Relationship 3">
                        </label>
                      </section>
                      <section class="col col-4">                            
                        <label class="input">
                          <input type="text" name="emergency_contact3" placeholder="Emergency Contact # 3"onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                        </label>
                      </section>
                    </div>  
                  </fieldset>


              </div>
              <!-- end widget content -->

            </div>
            <!-- end widget div -->

          </div>
          <!-- end widget -->

        </article>
      </form>
```

These are the routes

```
    Route::get('/employee/add', 'PagesController@addEmployee');
    Route::get('/employee/add/{paramStatus}', 'PagesController@addEmployee');
    Route::get('/employee/{id}/add', 'EmployeesController@editEmployee');
    Route::post('employee/{id}/ajaxShow', 'EmployeesController@ajaxShow');
    Route::post('employee/{id}/ajaxUpdate', 'EmployeesController@ajaxUpdate');
```

**PagesController.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;   
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use View;
    use App\Entry;
    use App\SSSSetting;
    use Request as Req;
    use App\manage;
    use DB;
    use App\Employee;

class PagesController extends Controller
{           
    public function addEmployee()
        {
            $breadcrumb = 'Employees > Add Employee';
            $pageTitle = 'CollabUX | Add Employee';
            $saveButtonText = "Add Employee";
            $prepath ='../';
            $currentURL = Req::url();
            $resultem = Employee::all();
            $EmployeeInfo = DB::table('employees')->get();      

            return View::make('employee.add')->with(
                array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb,'pageTitle' => $pageTitle,'currentURL' => $currentURL,
                    'saveButtonText' => $saveButtonText,'prepath' => $prepath,'resultem' => $resultem,'EmployeeInfo' => $EmployeeInfo));
        }

    public function editEmployee($id)
        {

            $breadcrumb = 'Employees > Manage Employees > Edit';
            $pageTitle = 'CollabUX | Edit Employee';
            $saveButtonText = "Save Changes";
            $prepath ='../';        
            $currentURL = Req::url();
            $resultem = manage::all();  
            $EmployeeInfo = DB::table('employees')->where('id', $id)->get(); 

            return View::make('employee.add')->with(
                array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb,'pageTitle' => $pageTitle,'currentURL' => $currentURL,
                    'saveButtonText' => $saveButtonText,'prepath' => $prepath,'resultem' => $resultem, ));
        }
}
```

**EmployeeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use App\Employee;
use Request as Req;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request){

        $first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $middle_name = $request->input('middle_name');
        $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $present_address = $request->input('present_address');
        $permanent_address = $request->input('permanent_address');
        $gender = $request->input('gender');
        $birthday = $request->input('birthday');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $work_phone = $request->input('work_phone');
        $home_phone = $request->input('home_phone');
        $mobile_phone = $request->input('mobile_phone');
        $religion = $request->input('religion');
        $citizenship = $request->input('citizenship');
        $civil_status = $request->input('civil_status');


        $data = array('id'=>$employeeNum,'first_name'=>$first_name,'middle_name'=>$middle_name,'last_name'=>$last_name,'present_address'=>$present_address,'permanent_address'=>$permanent_address,'email'=>$email,'work_phone'=>$work_phone,'home_phone'=>$home_phone,'mobile_phone'=>$mobile_phone,'religion'=>$religion,'gender'=>$gender,'birthday'=>$birthday,'citizenship'=>$citizenship);
        $save = DB::table('employees')->insert($data);

        return redirect('/employee/add');

        return view('add'); 

    }

    public function ajaxShow(Request $request, $id) {
        $manageEmployee = Employee::find($id);

        return array('status' => 'OK', 'result' => $manageEmployee);
    }

    public function editEmployee($id)
    {
        $breadcrumb = 'Employees > Manage Employees > Edit';
        $pageTitle = 'CollabUX | Edit Employee';
        $saveButtonText = "Save Changes";
        $currentURL = Req::url();
        $prepath ='../';
        $resultem = Employee::all();

        $EmployeeInfo = DB::table('employees')->where('id', $id)->get();    

        return view('employee.add')->with(array('breadcrumb'=>$breadcrumb,'pageTitle'=>$pageTitle,'currentURL' => $currentURL,'prepath'=>$prepath,'saveButtonText'=>$saveButtonText,'EmployeeInfo'=>$EmployeeInfo, 'resultem' => $resultem));

    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        // validate the data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'middle_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'present_address' => 'required',
            'permanent_address' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'birthday' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'work_phone' => 'required',
            'home_phone' => 'required',
            'religion' => 'required',
            'citizenship' => 'required'          
        ]);

        $manageEmployee = Employee::where('id', '!=', $id)->where(array('first_name' => $request->first_name, 'middle_name' => $request->middle_name,'last_name' => $request->last_name,'present_address' => $request->present_address,'permanent_address' => $request->permanent_address,'gender' => $request->gender,'birthday' => $request->birthday,'email' => $request->email,'work_phone' => $request->work_phone,'home_phone' => $request->home_phone,'religion' => $request->religion,'citizenship' => $request->citizenship,'civil_status' => $request->civil_status,'employeeNum' => $request->employeeNum,'Position' => $request->Position,'Supervisor' => $request->Supervisor,'starting_salary' => $request->starting_salary,'status' => $request->status,'tin' => $request->tin,'SSS' => $request->SSS,'philhealth' => $request->philhealth,'pagibig' => $request->pagibig,'no_dependents' => $request->no_dependents))->first();

        if ($manageEmployee)
            return array('status' => 'ERROR', 'error' => 'Record already exists.');

        $manageEmployee = Employee::find($id);

        if ($manageEmployee) {
            $manageEmployee->first_name = $request->first_name;
            $manageEmployee->middle_name = $request->middle_name;
            $manageEmployee->last_name = $request->last_name;
            $manageEmployee->present_address = $request->present_address;
            $manageEmployee->permanent_address = $request->permanent_address;
            $manageEmployee->gender = $request->gender;
            $manageEmployee->birthday = $request->birthday;
            $manageEmployee->email = $request->email;
            $manageEmployee->work_phone = $request->work_phone;
            $manageEmployee->home_phone = $request->home_phone;
            $manageEmployee->religion = $request->religion;
            $manageEmployee->citizenship = $request->citizenship;
            $manageEmployee->civil_status = $request->civil_status;
            $manageEmployee->employeeNum = $request->employeeNum;
            $manageEmployee->Position = $request->Position;
            $manageEmployee->Supervisor = $request->Supervisor;
            $manageEmployee->starting_salary = $request->starting_salary;
            $manageEmployee->status = $request->status;
            $manageEmployee->tin = $request->tin;
            $manageEmployee->SSS = $request->SSS;
            $manageEmployee->philhealth = $request->philhealth;
            $manageEmployee->pagibig = $request->pagibig;
            $manageEmployee->no_dependents = $request->no_dependents;

            $manageEmployee->save();
        }
        return array('status' => 'OK', 'result' => $manageEmployee);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you want to read about form model binding: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#form-model-binding
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-same-form-for-create-and-edit-page?page=1

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You have a very simple solution for this; viz. *Form-model binding*

Make three view files

```
 1. create.blade.php
 2. edit.blade.php
 3. _form.blade.php
```

_form.blade.php is a partial file which will be included in both `create` and `edit`.

Note: You will have to use the `laravelcollective/html` package.

**create.blade.php**

```
<!-- Your template HTML code here -->

{!! Form::open([
    'action' => 'EmployeesController@store',
    'id' => 'employee-form'
   ]) !!}
    @include('employee._form')
{!! Form::close() !!}

<!-- Continue with your template HTML code here -->
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<!-- Your template HTML code here -->

{!! Form::model([
    $employee,
    'method' => 'POST', <!-- Or whatever you have used for update() -->
    'action' => ['EmployeesController@update', $employee->id],
    'id' => 'employee-form'
   ]) !!}
    @include('employee._form')
{!! Form::close() !!}

<!-- Continue with your template HTML code here -->
```

**_form.blade.php**

```
<fieldset>                        
    <div class="row">
    <section class="col col-4">
      <label class="label">Full Name</label>
      <label class="input">
        {!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['placeholder => 'First Name']) !!}
      </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-4">
      <label class="label">&nbsp;</label>
      <label class="input">
        <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name">
        {!! Form::text('middle_name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Middle Name']) !!}
      </label>
    </section>
    ...
 </fieldset>
```

The form model binding will take care of populating the edit form fields with the stored values from the database.

---

If you want to avoid multiple view files:

Just have a single view, say `employee_form.blade.php`

```
<!-- Your template HTML code here -->
@if($employee instanceof \App\Employee)
  {!! Form::model([
    $employee,
    'method' => 'POST', <!-- Or whatever you have used for update() -->
    'action' => ['EmployeesController@update', $employee->id],
    'id' => 'employee-form'
   ]) !!}
@else
  {!! Form::model([
    $employee = new \App\Employee,
    'method' => 'POST', <!-- Or whatever you have used for store() -->
    'action' => ['EmployeesController@store', $employee->id],
    'id' => 'employee-form'
   ]) !!}
@endif
    @include('employee._form')
{!! Form::close() !!}

<!-- Continue with your template HTML code here -->
```

---

**Another suggestion**

Please don't put all your business logic in the Controllers.

Use `Request` classes for validations.

Try moving your business logic to other classes (like `Service` and `Repository` classes) to keep your controllers light-weight. Refer [this](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.WHG9N2efGDg) for example of how to make use of Helper classes to keep your code clean and manageable.

Comment: is it possible if i use only 1 view for my create and edit? cause i'm avoiding to have plenty of views...

Comment: You could avoid the use of the laravelcollecetive\html package as this isn't explicitly needed. To use fewer views in your application you could create one file for the create and edit forms which would check to see if the resource is set on the edit screen and add logic in there to add the resource inputs. In the create screen all inputs would then be blank.

Comment: @JoshBolton I'd still prefer `laravelcollective/html` package, as it does all the form-model binding out-of-the-box; so we can focus on our business logic. Also, less chance of introducing a bug in the code as the package is already tested.

Comment: @BiancaPiper Yes, you may use a single view. I added separate `create` and `edit` views just as an example (in case you need to show some extra info in the `edit` view). Just use form-model binding and you are good to go. See the updated answer.

Comment: im using Ajax to populate data is it ok? but its still not working though

Comment: Any specific reason for using AJAX?

Answer (score 3):

As Form-model binding is no longer included in Laravel core I personally wouldn't recommend it as the best solution. Look at route model binding and pure HTML forms and partials.